# Different field width on web page and in print preview in IE7+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I need to implement a pixel-perfect markup for IE7+. The problem I have encountered is the following: the width of the fields differs in web-page view and in print preview. See the following example:

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
    .input_multiline {
                    border:0;
                    height: 30px;
                    padding-left: 10px;
                    padding-top: 10px;
                    border-bottom:1px solid black;
                    font-family: monospace;
                    font-size:13pt;
                    margin-top:10px;
                }
    </style>

    <body>
        <input readonly = "readonly" class="input_multiline" style="width: 960px;" type="text" value="012345679 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 95chr"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

The input field here can hold 95 characters, but when I print it, it shows only 91 character. With different width and CSS setup the difference I got was up to 10 characters in a line.

Is there a way to somehow fix this and assure that the page I see in browser will be printed just the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get lines of the same width displayed on screen and printed on paper one should specify width in centimeters or inches and not in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

The number of characters that fit on a line in print media depends on the paper size, paper orientation, and margins. You cannot control them in HTML or CSS. (The `@page` things in CSS3 aren’t supported in IE.)

It also depends on the font, so if you need pixel-perfectness, set `font-family` to a specific font (not `monospace`, which depends on browser settings).

Whatever doesn’t fit on a printed line normally just gets ignored.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for the 'size' attribute:
[W3School link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_size.asp)

But to check why it looks different when you print it, you must take into consideration the whole stylesheet. There are also distinct media queries for print-layouts. Maybe you could just adapt the print layout to look the same as the normal one.

Comment: Setting `width` in CSS overrides the HTML `size` attribute.